# Invoke Google geocoder service from C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

while generating google map i am sending address to a java script function.sample code:--

**java script function code:--**

```
function codeAddress(address) {
        //            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        var address;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
```

`" 
**cs code  :--**
"

```
string addrs= "New York,USA";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "a", "codeAddress(" + addrs + ");", true);
```

" 
 i am using proper API Key and url. in html its working. but when i pass address from cs file its not working. why? how can i execute above java script function by passing address value.. is there any wrong in code... Thanks

Comment: codeAddress does not take any parameters but you are passing one in your code-behind.

Comment: i updated my code please check

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call google geocode service from c# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274508/how-to-call-google-geocode-service-from-c-sharp-code) (found googling "google map geocode c#" ... )

Comment: @Alex, don't you think his problem is related to ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: Place a console.log() at your first line of codeAddress and see if you are entering your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "a", "codeAddress('" + addrs + "');", true);
```

My guess is that it's not interpreted as a string without `''`.