# Errors compiling XML related sample

Tags: c#, xml

For the answer given on this question [How to call Google Geocoding service from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274508/how-to-call-google-geocode-service-from-c-sharp-code/28975452), I was unable to recreate the answer as it was provided.

Code in the post:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
```

I've added:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

with no luck - getting errors like

> 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and...

Comment: what is the type of `xdoc` ?

Comment: @Selman22 looks like an `XElement` or `XDocument`. @WayneJohn you can always put comments on your own posts and edit them. Now, to answer this, we would need to know what the xml you received looks like. Please edit this into your answer along with how you created the `xdoc` variable.

Comment: Everyone else - please don't downvote immediately. This question was asked 6 minutes ago and the OP is clearly trying to figure out the correct way to ask it. If he still hasn't figured it out in an hour or so downvote away.

Comment: Oh, also what version of the .Net framework are you using? And what are your project references?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer This looks like a compile time error, so the XML shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: WayneJohn - for future question please avoid "story of my life"/"thank you" text and provide enough context inline of the question (see my edit).

Comment: I usually only read here and rarely need to ask my own questions, but when I do it's rather frustrating to think that I'd need to create an entirely different question that points to another existing question.  If I were searching for an answer, as is my normal activity, I'd appreciate having everything under the same question rather than spread across several.

I don't care about downvotes, just looking for an answer.  

@George - Thanks for the assist.  I'm running .Net 4, referencing System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq.  It is a compile time issue.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I feel you have removed some important context that Selman22 could have used, but I'll be more terse here going forward.

Comment: @WayneJohn you're correct, in this specific case it would have been better to handle your issue in the comments to the other issue but - like you say, you did not have the reputation for this. That's unfortunate. However, the upside is that this question as it is written now will likely be useful for other users who mistake `XmlDocument` and `XDocument`.

Comment: WayneJohn - I thought I've actually added line @Selman22 was looking for - how xdoc was defined. If you feel that something is missing/wrong with any edit to your post you are the final authority on the changes - rollback, edit, suggest rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was invalid edit on the linked post that introduced this non-compilable code.

Correct code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
```

Make sure to add `using System.Xml.Linq;` and corresponding reference if missing - System.Xml.Linq.dll.

Comment: Side note: I've rolled back edit on the original http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274508/how-to-call-google-geocode-service-from-c-sharp-code/16275025#16275025 answer, so code there should work.

Comment: Good catch @WayneJohn note the big difference is the use of `XDocument` (which is part of Linq2Xml) and not `XmlDocument` (which is an older/different API)

Comment: I should have caught that myself.  Thanks for the assist all.