# Get mobile device current location in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, location, mobile-application

Iam working on asp.net application to track the current location of my customized mobile app. Currently the location(i.e) lat,long of the users will be feed into DB at real time.

Now I would like to show their location in a separate ASP.net application.

I searched a lot and could find only mobile applications to show their current location but not to track the location through ASP.Net app.

Need help in achieving this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to search for API of google map location service to embed it in asp.net.

Comment: @ArsalanHussain, I checked all the APIs but doesnt suits my need. I would like to post the current location of someone who uses my application, in a centralised dashboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824348/working-with-the-google-location-api
this link would help you out

Comment: Hope this would help you out.

Comment: Sorry @ArsalanHussain, my need is different with the geocoding, elevation and directions from Google API.